# Driving electronic card with half-bridge gate driver?

Tags: power-electronics, solid-state-relay

[image]

I want to switch a system like an SSR instead of a relay with a half bridge circuit, but I can't find a complete example. The question I'm wondering is, can I switch any electronic card with these drivers instead of driving a motor?

Comment: This is an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/): you are asking about proposed solution Y (how to use a half bridge circuit) to problem X (how to switch a system like an SSR). Please ask question X instead. Provide any and all supporting information so that question X can be answered. Thanks!